# Auto complete not working in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode9

I'm using Xcode 9.0.1. Previously when typing 'if' would auto complete the entire if block with parenthesis and brackets. With the latest update it doesn't do that anymore .

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes is an indexing problem or close and restart Xcode and then it starts working again ... weird.

Answer (score 0):

Let xcode complete the indexing of application files, SDK libraries, respective pods etc. If it doesn't work then quit and restart xcode.